# Stripe API - Can not retrieve products purchased from a pricing table using webhook or api

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-api-php

From the Stripe dashboard, I create some Products (standard pricing, one-time purchase), and then I create a Pricing Table that includes those products.

I then setup a webhook from Stripe to send the charge.succeeded event, the payment_intent.succeeded event and the checkout.session.completed event to my back end server.

When a product from the pricing table is purchased, I successfully receive the above webhook events.

But looking thru these events, there is no product information transmitted with any of the above events, so I do not know what product was purchased.

Each of the above event objects includes id's for other objects, so using the Stripe API I can retreive these other objects (like customer object), but I am still unable to find any product information in these other objects as well.

So I can retreive the **payment_intent** object, the **charge** object, the **checkout_session** object, and the **customer** object, but I am unable to figure out how to get to the **product** that was actually purchased.

NOTE: It looks like the checkout_session object id is the one I need (products purchased are called 'line items'), but for some reason, when I retrieve a Checkout Session object using 'expand line_items', it will not return any line items... I just get the exact same normal checkout session object as if I did not use expand line_items. According to the Stripe API docs, this is supposed to work, but it is not working for me. Per the Stripe API docs, this should work: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items

Code examples for PHP ... all of these calls below simply return the normal Checkout Session object with no line items:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('stripe_api_secret_key');

$get_line_items = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve( 'cs_checkout_session_object_id', [ 'expand' => ['line_items'] ] );
                        
$get_line_items = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve( 'cs_checkout_session_object_id', [ 'expand' => ['data.line_items'] ] );

$get_line_items = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve( 'cs_checkout_session_object_id', [ 'expand' => ['line_items.data'] ] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get `['expand' => ['line_items']]` to work, but I was able to retrieve the products that a customer purchased in a checkout_session using the `allLineItems` call in PHP (other languages use `listLineItems` or `list_line_items` calls).

The Stripe API docs are here for **Retrieve a Checkout Session's line items**:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items

EDIT: I have resolved the issue with 'expand line items'...

All the Stripe docs now refer to the newer interface method, but the old interface method is still available. However when using the old interface method, there were some quirks in how certain requests are made. Below is the correct way, in PHP, to make these calls using the old interface method.

```
// Setup for old interface method. 
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('stripe_api_secret_key');

// Expand line_items with retrieve checkout_session object. Note the poistion of square brackets and inclusion of 'id' to make this call work.
$get_line_items = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve(['id'=>'cs_test_123','expand'=>['line_items'], ]);

// Retrieve all line_items object. Note: check that your stripe-sdk-php version is new enough to support the allLineItems call.
$get_line_items = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::allLineItems('cs_test_123');
```

Answer (score 2):

To attain the product that was purchased via a CheckoutSession, you can look at the `line_items` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items). This is what they call an includable property where it’s not included by default. So, you’d need to use the expand request [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) when you retrieve the [CheckoutSession](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve). Here is a cURL request from their [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/expand#includable-properties):

`curl -G https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/{{SESSION_ID}} \ -u sk_test_123: \ -d "expand[]"=line_items`

Comment: Using the 'expand line_items' parameter, I get the same checkout_session object back that is identical to if I did not use the 'expand line_items'. There is no additional data and no line items.

Comment: The CheckoutSession ID would be the same since you're retrieving the CheckoutSession by that ID. When you expand the `line_items` you should get the product ID.

Comment: I know that is what SHOULD happen, but for some reason, it is not... even with 'expand line_items', I am not getting any line items back. However, this did lead to a soltuion that works, using the allLineItems/listLineItems call which I will post below.